# How to make the date become the first column?

Tags: r, rename, col

I want to make the date become the first column of `SBUX`, which means there should be a total of 7 column for `SBUX`. What should I do to the code?

```
library(quantmod)

stocks <- getSymbols("SBUX", from="2017-01-01", periodicity = "weekly")
SBUX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is what you want - it will extract the dates from SBUX as a vector.

However, the data in SBUX is stored in a matrix, and in R, a matrix can only contain data of a single type (in this case, a double).  If you want to add a Date column, you'll first need to make it a data frame.

So the following should work:

```
library(quantmod)

stocks <- getSymbols("SBUX", from="2017-01-01", periodicity = "weekly")
dates <- index(SBUX)
SBUX <- as.data.frame(SBUX)
SBUX <- cbind(date = dates, SBUX)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, that's what I'm looking for! However, how should I do to remove the index of the dataframe so that there is only the first column (date) without the index itself. Because after I run the code, it shows me 2 column of date, one is the first column and another one is the index.

Comment: The first column there is the rownames.  If you want to remove that, you can just set the rownames to null: `rownames(SBUX) <- NULL`